# Navigate through dynamically generated detail pages - OpenUi5

Tags: javascript, tree, sapui5

I have a splitApp with a Tree in the Master Page and each time a treeNode is expanded, I generate a new Detail Page and display it in the detail section. I want to be able to navigate back to the previous detail Page but I don't know how can I achieve that.

```
var app = this.getView().byId("SplitAppDemo");
var page = new sap.m.Page({
                title: lItem,
                showNavButton: true,
                navButtonPress: function(){
                    app.getSplitAppObj().backDetail();
                }
            }); 
app.addDetailPage(page);
app.toDetail(page);
```

The lItem is the text of the node. In this code I get an error that "app.getSplitAppObj()" is not a function.

Any ideas? 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple:

```
var page = new sap.m.Page({
            title: lItem,
            showNavButton: true,
            navButtonPress: function(){
                app.backDetail();
            }
        });
```